# Find the third side of a triangle with two sides and a median

Tags: trigonometry

Looking to find the BC side knowing AM is the median... what would the approach be considering we have no angle? Using sine and cosine rules (not Stewart theorem). I tried with a system of equations but I can't figure it out.

[image]

Comment: You can only receive help if you indicate your efforts to solve the problem. Here is a hint regardless, try cosine rule using angles $AMC$ and also $AMB$, or equivalently stewart's theorem. Do note $\cos(x) = -\cos(180^{\circ} - x)$

Comment: @Sahaj Thanks. Yes sorry I should've indicated what I tried to do. I was more looking for a way to solve with without Stewart's theorem as it wasn't explored in the context of our course. Your input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I couldn't write a long comment to help you out. So I've added it as an answer instead.

Comment: Thanks, no problem. That is helpful for sure! It certainly gives me a different approach to that problem that I wasn't thinking about.

Comment: @hawks10: Can you look up Stewart' Law and its derivation $ m_a=\sqrt{2(b^2+c^2)-a^2}/2$

Comment: @Narasimham Thanks for your input. I was looking for another way to approach this problem as this strategy wasn't mentioned in the context of our course.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the side you're looking for is $2x$ (only for the sake of simplicity), then $BM=MC=x$. Using law of cosines on triangle $AMB$, you get:

$$4^2 = (3.5)^2 + x^2 - 7x\cos(AMB)$$

Similarly on $AMC$ while noting $\cos(\pi-x) = -\cos(x)$:

$$7^2 = (3.5)^2 + x^2 - 7x\cos(AMC)$$
$$7^2 = (3.5)^2 + x^2 - 7x\cos(\pi - AMB) \implies 7^2 = (3.5)^2 + x^2 + 7x\cos(AMB)$$
Add these two equations:
$$65 = 2(3.5)^2 +2x^2 \implies x = \dots?$$

Note this is Stewart's theorem in disguise.

---

More generally for any triangle $ABC$, with some median $m_a$ which bisects side $a$ at $D$, you have the following two equations:

$$b^2 = m_a^2 + \frac{a^2}{4} - m_a\cdot a\cdot \cos(ADC)$$ and $$c^2 = m_a^2 + \frac{a^2}{4} - m_a \cdot a \cdot cos(ADB) \implies c^2 = m_a^2 + \frac{a^2}{4} + m_a\cdot a\cos(ADC)$$

Adding these two equations, you find that:

$$b^2 + c^2 = 2(m_a^2)+\frac{a^2}{2}$$
And that means:

$$m_a^2 = \frac{b^2}{2}+\frac{c^2}{2} - \frac{a^2}{4}$$

This result is called the Theorem of Apollonius.

Comment: I didn't realize I had made a couple of typing errors. Sorry!